# vue.js - Multiple language in popup using i18n

Tags: vue.js, popup, vue-i18n

I am creating a component with a button show a popup using [vue-sweetalert2](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2).
In the popup, there are have 2 buttons that I want to display multiple language
(I am using i18n for multiple language for every word in `template` tag but the popup texts are in `script->export default->method`)

```
methods:{
    openAlert(){
        this.$swal({
            title: 'Confirm Popup',
            text: "File name is duplicate \n What do you want?", //<--here i want multiple language
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonText: 'Replace file', //<-- here
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Cancel upload' // <--- here
            })
    },
```

}

Please help me! I'm new in JS

Comment: Don't you think language selection should be a simple dropdown in header or footer and not an alert.

Comment: i did do the dropdown in header, that could change the language of all text in template but not include the text in the popup. I want to change language of the popup too

Comment: What issue are you facing in replacing the text of popups also using i18n? Guess you just need to add keys and use them accordingly in pop up too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a select in alert as shown below.

```
this.$swal({
  title: 'Confirm Popup',',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    '1': 'Value 1',
    '2': 'Value 2',
    '3': 'Value 3'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'required',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: function (value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (value !== '') {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject('You need to select a Value');
      }
    });
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  if (result.value) {
    this.$swal({
      type: 'success',
      html: 'You selected: ' + result.value
    });
  }
});
```

You can also refer to the [example](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true) in official documentation.